# What does boost::container::allocator_traits::is_partially_propagable mean?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-container

I was tring to understand [boost::container::allocator_traits](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/doc/html/boost/container/allocator_traits.html) when I encountered boost::container::allocator_traits::is_partially_propagable.

I can't find any other document about it online, and I can understand all the other members of boost::container::allocator_traits except is_partially_propagable and storage_is_unpropagable.

Edit:

And, how they're implemented and how to use them when writing a container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It (`is_partially_propagable`) means that the allocator uses internal storage (it has state), and not all memory allocated by it can be deallocated by another allocator, even if both compare equal. (Allocators of the same type are supposed to always compare equal and be interchangeable)

What `storage_is_unpropagable` does is take a pointer to allocated memory and return `true` if this is memory that is not propagable. (Since not all memory has to be unpropagable)

This allocator (`small_vector_allocator`) is used as a space optimization in `small_vector`.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_0/boost/container/small_vector.hpp

Comment: Can you explain how they are implemented?

Comment: Also, can you talk more about how to use them when writing a container?

Comment: @JiaHaoXu I am not sure about this particular allocator. But I have used other allocators that have an internal buffer (i.e. a byte array member with the size of some template parameter) and return pointers to this internal buffer when allocating until it is depleted, at which point they simply forward the `allocate()` call to the default allocator (i.e. `new`). These allocators are good for containers that need many small allocations (and no deallocations).

Comment: About ```Allocators of the same type are supposed to always compare equal and be interchangeable```, there's no restriction on equality of objects of same type that in boost::container::allocator_traits.

Comment: @JiaHaoXu The restriction is in the C++ Standard, and this exception to the rule is boost specific.

Comment: It's just for ```std::allocator```, there's no restriction on custom allocator. So, things are more complicated.